# 192.168.2.xxx devices cannot ping to 192.168.3.xxx with same subnet mask 255.255.255.0

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

I have the following network setup

1. Main Router (ASUS 5300) 192.168.2.1 - Connected to the Cable Modem and Connects to the Internet with Default Gateway as 192.168.2.1

   - This is the Main router connected to the Modem with > 80 devices (PC's, Servers etc..)
2. Router 2 192.168.3.x (ASUS 3200) - Connected to Main Router with WAN and DHCP Enabled (I get different set of IPs with 192.168.3.xx) with Default Gateway as 192.168.2.1

   - This is for all my Home Automation connections (I have > 50 devices: Alexa + Wink + HomeBridge etc..)
3. Router 3 192.168.4.x (ASUS 1200) - Connected to Main Router with WAN and DHCP Enabled (I get different set of IPs with 192.168.3.xx) with Default Gateway as 192.168.2.1

   - This is for my streaming devices (FireTv's etc)
4. Router 4 192.168.5.x (ASUS N53) - Connected to Main Router with WAN and DHCP Enabled (I get different set of IPs with 192.168.3.xx) with Default Gateway as 192.168.2.1

   - This is for a separate NW all together. I can get stop this but had router available to trying to play with Open WRT

All the devices can connect to the internet no issues. All the devices get unique IP's as well. 
The issue is that if I am connected to 2 Separate NW i cannot access any of the machines across them i.e. a NAS or Shared Folder or a Raspi Machine on 192.168.3.yy cannot be accessed with a PC on 192.168.2.yy and vice versa.

I would like to access ALL machines on either of the NW when connected from either of the routers.

**Update Configuration**

Internet Modem (ATT) 192.168.l.254

Main R1 (ASUS 5300) 192.168.2.1-Connected to the Cable Modem and Connects to the Internet with Default Gateway as 192.168.1.254 (ATT Modem)

R2 192.168.3.x(ASUS 3200)-WAN IP from R1 192.168.2.239(Static), DG-192.168.2.1,Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0, WAN+NAT+DHCP Enabled

R3 192.168.4.x(ASUS 1200)-WAN IP from R1 192.168.2.238(Static), DG-192.168.2.1,Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0, WAN+NAT+DHCP Enabled

R4 192.168.5.x(ASUS N53)-WAN IP from R1 192.168.2.240(Static), DG-192.168.2.1,Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0, WAN+NAT+DHCP Enabled

**R2 Config**

Under Console | LAN | Routing --> I added the routing

Network/Host IP          Netmask          Gateway          Metric          Interface

192.168.2.1          255.255.255.0          192.168.2.1          1          LAN

I did not add any other Routing for R1, 3, 4 (I know R3 and 4 wont work but I wanted to test with R2 first then apply it across)
I believe I am entering incorrect values in the routing table which is where I need help.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you added any routes telling the routers where all other networks are?

Comment: not yet. i tried based on several websites and link but i think i am doing something incorrect since it stopped connecting to the Internet and access to the router completely. If you can provide a sample would be helpful

Comment: See e.g. [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1372629/networking-between-two-subnets-mutually-instead-of-one-way/1372634#1372634)... would be better if you posted your current configuration attempts, to figure out exactly what went wrong, rather than just blindly following yet another tutorial.

Comment: i updated the configuration above in the main post as it did not allow me to save all the characters